# merged two bufferimages javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am working in javafx BufferedImage.
I have two BufferedImages 1)Grayscaleimage and 2)rgbimage. 
i want to merged this two images in that rgb image want to transperanet with black color.

How can i achirve this?

my code snippet is:

```
if (depth == 24) 
{
    bufferedImgCFM = getPixelArrayToBmpByteArray(
            fbData.getBuf(), width, height, depth);
}
else
{
    bufferedImgBMode = getPixelArrayToBmpByteArray(
            fbData.getBuf(), width, height, depth);
}

finalimage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) finalimage.getGraphics();

if (bufferedImgBMode != null) {
    g.drawImage(bufferedImgBMode, 0, 0, width, height, null);

}
if (bufferedImgCFM != null) {
    g.drawImage(bufferedImgCFM, 0, 0, width, height, null);
}

Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(finalimage, null);
```

getPixelArrayToBmpByteArray method is:

```
private BufferedImage getPixelArrayToBmpByteArray(byte[] pixelData, int width,
        int height, int depth) throws Exception {
    int[] pixels = byteToInt(pixelData);

    BufferedImage image = null;
    if (depth == 8) {
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    } else if (depth == 24) {
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        //int[][] result = new int[height][width];
    }

    WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) image.getData();
    raster.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixels);
    image.setData(raster);

    return image;
}
```

When i merged this two images second image that is rgb image will hide first image. i want to transperant rgb image with black.

Comment: Are you trying to watermark an image on another ?